# Unattended Mode changes to Suspend after one minute

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce, power-management

In my application (C#, .Net CE 3.5, WM 6.5), I have a thread that do sync with a web service. I want thread keep running if device goes to idle mode. So I use some Windows CE API, to run my thread in unattended mode and keep WiFi on during this process. (API from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873816/keep-windows-mobile-app-running-in-standby-mode)). This works perfectly and system goes to standby instead suspend and thread run with WiFi is on. But 1 minute after standby, device goes to Suspend mode and execution stops.

```
Win32.CoreDLL.PowerPolicyNotify(Win32.PPNMessage.PPN_UNATTENDEDMODE, -1);
IntPtr wifiHabdle= Win32.CoreDLL.SetPowerRequirement(wifiDeviceName,  CEDEVICE_POWER_STATE.D1, DevicePowerFlags.POWER_NAME | DevicePowerFlags.POWER_FORCE, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

//Connect to web service and do jobs ...

Win32.CoreDLL.ReleasePowerRequirement(wifiHabdle);
Win32.CoreDLL.PowerPolicyNotify(Win32.PPNMessage.PPN_UNATTENDEDMODE, 0);
```

When I change power configuration on device and set "Turn off screen if device not used for" to 2 minutes, unattended mode become 2 minutes before going to suspend. (strange relation).  How can I force device to remain in Unattended mode
as long as I call `PowerPolicyNotify(Win32.PPNMessage.PPN_UNATTENDEDMODE, 0)`

Comment: AFAIK you need to use SetPowerRequirement also for your application or use SystemIdleTimerReset periodically: http://www.brianpeek.com/category/Windows-Mobile ~ josef

Comment: @josef, that's the correct answer.  Put it in as an answer so you can get credit for it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you need to use SetPowerRequirement also for your application and/or use SystemIdleTimerReset periodically: http://www.brianpeek.com/category/Windows-Mobile

Although, in the past I did not success with SystemIdleTimerReset and instead changed the timeouts for battery powermanagement to suspend never and control the power requirements directly (request unattended mode).